# My question was downvoted and close because I posted it before I had all the information, please re-open it

Tags: support

I had posted my question and had only half completed it, the first half contained my full code that was out sourced on another website, because I had done so I had immediately gone back in to fix the rest of the question. I added the code but by the time I was finished I had a -5 down vote and I then said that I had fixed the question yet it was put on hold even though the question was correctly finished and had clearly said that I had fix the post in the comments.

I am now not able to ask any other questions, I need to be able to ask these questions so I may progress easily

Question: [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22561367/referencing-classes-and-string-use)

Comment: Improve your existing posts that have a negative score or that are put on hold. And do not delete questions.

Comment: In the future, consider deleting your post, copying the text to a markdown editor (where you can improve the post in your own time), then undeleting it when it's fixed.

Comment: @Qantas94Heavy The post is 100% correct, it is on topic, I see nothing wrong with the post. There is no need to fix the post. I want to know how to get a post, which is already correct back to a normal number instead of -5. Or at least allow me to get the question off hold so the person who correctly answer the question can get credit.

Comment: @RyanFoy: you said that you hadn't completed the post when you had posted it accidentally, didn't you? I'd posted that for future reference, not for the current situation you're in.

Comment: The fix I see in in the answer does not appear to have general applicability. This is a "well, your code is tripping over itself" kind of problem. Not a good fit for SO.

Comment: I am sorry I don't understand Louis, tripped over itself? You mean that my question does not give enough information? Or that the question is not clear as I said it was?

Comment: Thank you everyone for help but I am still unable to access "Ask Question" on SO, what else must I do to have access back to my account?

Comment: I gave you an up-vote in an attempt to stem the tide. :)

Comment: @Moo-Juice Thank you, I am now able to post questions again. I thank you all for helping, I am in the middle of creating a game for a class project at my tech center, I am the only working on coding side of it so I need to ask questions constantly to get any were. I have have asked the question on the [game devs stackX](http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/72481/tile-system-with-moving-platforms), if you want to see it just click the link.

Comment: @Ryan, just remember, if you were blocked from asking questions a moment a go you're right on the edge now, so be careful to keep your question quality high since a downvote or 2 could easily push you back over the edge.

Comment: That's a pretty bad question.  It's a huge dump of code, way, way, more code than should be posted, almost no description of what's going on, what it should be doing, barely a description of what's wrong, certainly not enough detail, no indication of where the problem is located.  I'm frankly quite disappointing that this question managed to get 6 upvotes, as it's very poorly constructed; clearly you should have spent quite a bit more time bringing your code sample down to a *minimal* reproducible example.  There should be at least 1/3 of the code that's there now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I should have not pressed the button, I should have not had an off the website link to the code unless necessary, and should state the question clearly by stating in bold the problem or some other way that will indicate that it is important to read.